# DroidDraw does not support Tab implementation

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to include tab implementation in AnDroidDraw code?
 I have downloaded the AnDroidDraw code from http://code.google.com/p/droiddraw/source/browse/#svn/trunk, but does not provide `TabHost` and `TabWidget` implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs are not supported in DroidDraw and DroidDraw hasn't been updated for a long time. Neither does the Eclipse Android GUI editor support tabs very well. Best to handle tabs yourself manually in your xml and code.

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are provided now (r1b19), you first have to select TabHost and then add a LinearLayout. And then put the Tab Widget in the LinearLayout.